# Show that the odd prime divisors of $n^2+1$ are of form $4k+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that the odd prime divisors of $n^2+1$ are of form $4k+1$

---

I have below so far

$n^2 + 1 \equiv  0 \mod p_i$
$n^4  \equiv  1 \mod p_i$
$4 \mid \phi(p_i)$

I am not sure where to go from here. Any hint/help ?

Comment: You almost have it: note that $\phi (p_i) = p_i - 1$ for $p_i$ prime, so $p_i - 1 = 4k$ for some integer $k$, therefore, $p_i$ is of the form $4k+1$.

Comment: OMG! yes :) that didn't strike me! thank you !!!

Comment: @DarthGeek: Please consider making your comment an answer, so that the OP can accept it, and this question will exit the unanswered queue.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan done.

Comment: How can we prove the converse statement ?   That is , if $p = 4k + 1$  ,then  $n^2 \equiv -1 (mod p)  $ , where $p$ is prime ?

Comment: @KierenMacMillan I don't get how $4|\varphi(p)$ comes. Could you shed a light on this way please? I'm asking you because you seem to be the one who most recently visited SE among them :)

Answer (score 3):

As requested I'm including the answer given in the comment as an answer.

Since $4\mid \phi(p_i) = p_i -1$ then $p_i-1 = 4k$ for some integer $k$. And thus $p_i$ is of the form $4k+1$ as desired.