# Describe the Natural density of $p$ which divides natural numbers of the form $n^2+1$?

Tags: divisibility

We want to find the numbers that divide natural numbers in the form of $n^2+1$ and solve for their natural density.

Using Wolfram Mathematica, I found divisors from $n=0$ to $1000000$ and eliminated repeated divisors. Here is the list

$$\left\{1,2,5,10,13,17,25,26,29,34,37,41,50,53,58,61,65,73,74,82,85,89,97,101,106,109,113,122,125,130,137,145,146,149,157,169,170,173,178,181,185,193,194,197,202,205,218,221,226,229,233,241,250,257,265,269,274,277,281..... \right\}$$

After looking at the list extensively my guess is the density is zero.

Is there a mathematical way of finding this without computer programming?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91648/discussion-on-question-by-arbuja-describe-the-asymptotic-density-of-p-prime-a).

Comment: The divisors of $n^2+1$ are precisely the numbers not divisible by four and with no prime factor  one less than a multiple of four. These are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A008784 and there are links there which may lead to an answer to your question.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472923/prime-divisors-of-x2-1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926561/show-that-the-odd-prime-divisors-of-n21-are-of-form-4k1

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A008784

Comment: I would suggest eliminating your initial general question, which is hopelessly broad.  The specific question about numbers of the form $n^2+1$ is a perfectly good question though.

Comment: @EricWofsey I deleted my initial general question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set in question, call it $A$, is a proper subset of the set, call it $B$, of numbers which can be written as a sum of two squares (the difference between the two sets is that $B$ is the set of all numbers of the form $2^rPQ^2$ where $r$ is a nonnegative integer, the prime factors of $P$ are all $1\bmod4$, and the prime factors of $Q$ are all $3\bmod4$; $A$ is the same, but with $r\le1$ and $Q=1$).

$B$ has density zero (and so, a fortiori, $A$ has density zero). This is discussed at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/205862/sums-of-two-squares-positive-lower-density and at the links to be found there. It goes back to Landau.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, you claim that every divisor of a number of the form $n^2+1$ belongs to one of some set of residue classes (mod 72).

This appears to be true.  For instance if any multiple of 3 were to divide $n^2+1$ then we would have $n^2+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ and in turn $n^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$.  But -1 is not a quadratic residue (mod 3), so we can rule out classes like 72m, 72m+3, etc. as potential divisors of $n^2+1$.

I didn't verify your list, but clearly some such list exists.

If you wanted to go from here to calculating the asymptotic density, you'd need to prove something stronger, say that *every* (perhaps sufficiently large) number belonging to such a class divides some number of the form $n^2+1$.

**UPDATE**

In fact let's consider that question.  Say you have some number $72m + r$ and claim it divides a number of the form $n^2 + 1$.  That is, for some k we have $(72m + r)k = n^2 + 1$.  Then $-1 + (72m+r)k$ is a perfect square for some $k>0$.  But this is the same as $-1$ being a quadratic residue $\pmod{72m+r}$.

My elementary number theory is rusty, but I think that's equivalent to every odd prime divisor of $72m+r$ being of the form $1 \pmod{4}$.  So you could try and see whether this applies to all numbers in such a class.

Comment: It is a valiant effort to make sense of the Question, but the considerations you give do not help in determining "density".  Showing that certain residues mod $72$ are possible as divisors of numbers of the form $n^2+1$ does not by itself guarantee all such residues as asymptotically equally likely.  I applaud your effort to reason on this, but I'm voting to close the Question as the OP has twice asked pretty much the same ill-defined problem.

Comment: @hardmath lulu in the discussion, understands my question. What is still unclear?

Comment: @Arbuja:  With more recent edits to your Question, I'm now able to upvote both it and Daniel's Answer.